# Bind Event Handlers within a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm trying to bind events to dynamically created menu item's click event that is created in a for loop. When I click the menu item, the code executes, but it's with the last value of "x" within the loop. This is the code:

```
        for(int x = 1; x < 3; x++)
        {
            MenuItem mi = new MenuItem("Get");
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            mi.Click += (s, e) => { GetClick(x); };
            cm.MenuItems.Add(mi);
            Button btn = this.Controls.Find("btnGet" + x.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
            btn.ContextMenu = cm;

        }

    private void GetClick(int intGetItem)
    {
        //Previous code...

        GetItem(intGetItem);
    }
```

The issue is when I debug the GetClick Method, intGetItem is always equal to 3 no matter which button I use. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign x to a local variable and use this in your expression:

```
var y = x;
mi.Click += (s, e) => { GetClick(y); };
```

here is an explanation: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

You can't define the parameters of an event when you register for it. Instead you should pass on the parameters that the menu item will supply.

```
mi.Click += GetClick;
```

And change your event to get the standard Click parameters:

```
private void GetClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == menu1) {...
```

Comment: I don't understand your remark. In his case, the event handler is the LINQ expression (s, e) => ... which is OK.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter - oh sorry, I missed that bit. I'm not sure if OP is just using the wrong syntax to do something simple, or trying to do something complicated that I don't understand. I'll edit my answer for the simple case.